# SpringFramework registerWebSocketHandlers not working

Tags: java, spring, websocket

I am trying to register a AbstractWebSocketHandler implementation in a class that implements SpringFrameworks WebSocketConfigurer and extends SpringFrameworks AbstractWebSocketMessageBrokerConfigurer. In the websockethandler, I print out messages on the afterConnectionEstablished and afterConnectionClosed methods but I never see those messages in the appserver logs. I haven't been able to determine what I am doing incorrectly yet. Any advice you can give will be very much appreciated.

AbstractWebSocketHandler class:

```
import org.apache.logging.log4j.LogManager;
import org.apache.logging.log4j.Logger;
import org.springframework.web.socket.CloseStatus;
import org.springframework.web.socket.WebSocketSession;
import org.springframework.web.socket.handler.AbstractWebSocketHandler;

public class ImomWebSocketHandler extends AbstractWebSocketHandler {

    private static final Logger logger = LogManager.getLogger();

    @Override
    public void afterConnectionEstablished(WebSocketSession session) throws Exception {
        logger.info("Connection established");
        System.out.println("ImomWebSocketHandler Connection Established");
        // this is where the IMOM Analysis Engine connection will be established
    }

    @Override
    public void afterConnectionClosed(WebSocketSession session, CloseStatus status) throws Exception {
        logger.info("Connection closed. Status: " + status);
        System.out.println("ImomWebSocketHandler Connection closed. Status: " + status);
        // this is where the IMOM Analysis Engine connection will be closed
    }
}
```

WebSocketConfigurer class:

```
import org.springframework.context.annotation.Bean;
import org.springframework.context.annotation.Configuration;
import org.springframework.messaging.simp.config.MessageBrokerRegistry;
import org.springframework.web.socket.config.annotation.AbstractWebSocketMessageBrokerConfigurer;
import org.springframework.web.socket.config.annotation.EnableWebSocket;
import org.springframework.web.socket.config.annotation.EnableWebSocketMessageBroker;
import org.springframework.web.socket.config.annotation.StompEndpointRegistry;
import org.springframework.web.socket.config.annotation.WebSocketConfigurer;
import org.springframework.web.socket.config.annotation.WebSocketHandlerRegistry;
import org.springframework.web.socket.server.standard.ServletServerContainerFactoryBean;

import gov.inl.ecsi.websocket.handler.ImomWebSocketHandler;

@Configuration
@EnableWebSocketMessageBroker
@EnableWebSocket
public class ImomWebSocketConfig extends AbstractWebSocketMessageBrokerConfigurer implements WebSocketConfigurer 
{       
    // This exposes a STOMP WebSocket/SockJS endpoint at the URL path /imom where 
    // messages whose destination starts with "/command/ae" are routed to 
    // message-handling methods (i.e. application work) with MessageMapping /command/ae annotation
    // The messages whose destinations start with "/topic" or "/queue" will be routed to the 
    // message broker (i.e. broadcasting to other connected clients)
    // It is very common, however, for destinations to be path-like strings 
    // where "/topic/.." implies publish-subscribe (one-to-many) and 
    // "/queue/" implies point-to-point (one-to-one) message exchanges.
    @Override
    public void configureMessageBroker(final MessageBrokerRegistry registry) {
        registry.enableSimpleBroker(new String[] { "/topic", "/queue" });
        registry.setApplicationDestinationPrefixes(new String[] { "/imom" });
    }

    // this is the websocket STOMP endpoint, it goes with the MessageMapping
    @Override
    public void registerStompEndpoints(StompEndpointRegistry arg0) {
        // Client connects to var socket = new SockJS('/GCCSWebSocketApp/command');
        arg0.addEndpoint(new String[] { "/command" }).withSockJS();
    }

    //
    // http://docs.spring.io/spring/docs/current/spring-framework-reference/html/websocket.html#websocket-server-runtime-configuration
    // Each underlying WebSocket engine exposes configuration properties that
    // control runtime characteristics such as the size of message buffer sizes,
    // idle timeout, and others.
    //
    // For Tomcat, WildFly, and GlassFish add a
    // ServletServerContainerFactoryBean to your WebSocket Java config
    @Bean
    public ServletServerContainerFactoryBean createWebSocketContainer() {
        ServletServerContainerFactoryBean container = new ServletServerContainerFactoryBean();
        container.setMaxTextMessageBufferSize(32768);
        container.setMaxBinaryMessageBufferSize(32768);
        return container;
    }

    @Override
    public void registerWebSocketHandlers(WebSocketHandlerRegistry arg0) {
        arg0.addHandler(imomWebSocketHandler(), "/imom").withSockJS();
    }

    @Bean
    public ImomWebSocketHandler imomWebSocketHandler() {
        return new ImomWebSocketHandler();
    }
}
```

log4j2.xml

```
<Configuration status="warn" monitorInterval="30">
    <Appenders>
        <Console name="Console" target="SYSTEM_OUT">
            <PatternLayout pattern="[%t] %d{HH:mm:ss} %c{1} [%p] - %m%n"/>
        </Console>
        <!-- <RollingFile name="LogFile" fileName="C:/Temp/ImomLogfile.log"
                filePattern="C:/Temp/ImomLogfile-%d{yyyy-MM-dd}-%i.log.zip">
            <PatternLayout pattern="[%t] %d{yyyy-MM-dd HH:mm:ss.SSS} %c [%p] - %m%n"/>
            <Policies>
                <TimeBasedTriggeringPolicy />
                <SizeBasedTriggeringPolicy size="10 MB"/>
            </Policies>
            <DefaultRolloverStrategy max="5"/>
        </RollingFile> -->
    </Appenders>
    <Loggers>
        <Root level="trace">
            <AppenderRef ref="Console"/>
        </Root>
        <Logger name="gov.inel" level="info" additivity="false">
            <AppenderRef ref="Console" level="info"/>
            <!-- <AppenderRef ref="LogFile" level="info"/> -->
        </Logger>
        <Logger name="gov.inl" level="info" additivity="false">
            <AppenderRef ref="Console" level="info"/>
            <!-- <AppenderRef ref="LogFile" level="info"/> -->
        </Logger>
        <Logger name="imom" level="info" additivity="false">
            <AppenderRef ref="Console" level="info"/>
            <!-- <AppenderRef ref="LogFile" level="info"/> -->
        </Logger>
        <Logger name="org" level="info" additivity="false">
            <AppenderRef ref="Console" level="error"/>
            <!-- <AppenderRef ref="LogFile" level="error"/> -->
        </Logger>
    </Loggers>
</Configuration>
```

Comment: Can you post your log4j configuration (xml or properties) file

Comment: I added my log4j which is logging to System out but the callback code is also doing a system.out.printlin. Neither show up in my tomcat stdout log file.